# Checking that a user is travelling in the direction of a given Location

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location, google-play-services

I want to be able to determine on Android if a user is travelling in the direction of a given Location or away from it. I'm receiving regular location updates from a Service, and would like to know how I could go about this as I seem to be drawing up blanks when thinking about it. I'm using the fusedlocation provider for location updates.

Basic scenario:

Location L1, Location L2
Users location is updated periodically
Once user is in range of L1, notify the user only once
If user is now heading towards L2 thats fine
If not notify user that they are going in the wrong direction

**Code Snippets**

On location change broadcast an intent with the new location

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(NavigationAnimatorActivity.INTENT_ACTION);
    i.putExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED, location);

    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            i.getExtras().get(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED)
                    .toString());

    // Broadcast the intent carrying the data

    sendBroadcast(i);

}
```

Handle the location data

```
class ReceiveLocationUpdate extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String action = intent.getAction();

        // send message to activity

        Bundle b = null;

        // Check we have a bundle
        if ((b = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
            // Check if we have location data
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(INTENT_ACTION)) {

                Object o = b.get(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
                Log.v(getClass().getName(), o.toString());
                if (o != null && o instanceof Location) {
                    mCurrentLocation = (Location) o;                        
                    checkIfAtLocation(mCurrentLocation);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Check if we're near a location we need to notify the user of

```
private void checkIfAtLocation(Location currLocation) {

        Location L1 = s.asLocation();
        Location L2; // Next waypoint           

        // Check if we're within range of a waypoint, notifying user if we are
        if (mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(L1)) <= RADIUS) {

            // Notify Once

            // How do I check that user is travelling towards L2?
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad. Please update it in a way a programmer would try it. Fragments of the algorithm would be the best.

Comment: Also for clarification: mCurrentlocation is what I'm getting from location updates. L1, and L2 are the two Locations I'm interested in. Once the user is in range of L1, I want to make sure they are travelling in the direction of L2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate if the user is approaching a point:
use the `Location.distanceTo()` method: pass in current lat,lon and destination lat/lon,
and store that distance;

After a while do the same again, and compare if current distance now is smaller than old distance.
If distance is smaller then the approaches the destination, if it is greater he moves away.
If distance < 50m, he has reached the destination.